# Collision with rotating rectangles using libgdx?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

In my game, the player is a circle texture, and there are lots of tall, narrow, rotating square textures. I know how to use the `Intersector` class for collision, but from what I have discovered, it doesn't account for rotation. Is there some way/class that can create shapes from a texture, then use those as the bounds?

Comment: This feels like a [mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) question.  Google is also your friend.

Comment: @markspace Not really. I need a way to extract a collision bound from the sprite/texture accounting for rotation which is able to be used with something like Intersector. I have googled the crap out of this question, haven't found anything on it.

Comment: Not saying this is the best solution, but you could make polygons out of them. Polygons can be rotated.

Comment: @eric Do you know of any way to automatically create polygons from textures?

Comment: Well if you know the width and height of the texture, you can create a polygon from it. The polygon constructor takes an array of vertices. So You would have 4 vertices. Bottom Left (0,0) Top Left (0, texture.height), Top Right (texture.width, texture.height) and Bottom Right (texture.width, 0). That would create a polygon that can be rotated and then you can handle collision with a polygon.

Comment: @Wyatt, you keep mentioning Textures. Maybe you're complicating the issue by conflating rendering with physics. Textures are for rendering. You just need shapes for calculating the collisions. No need to involve the textures, is there? If your collision boundaries are not rectangles, then you might need some physics editing app for generating collision meshes, something like this: https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor

Comment: @eric Is there any way to render a polygon, so that I can check and make sure I got the bounds correctly?

Comment: @Wyatt I use a ShapeRenderer when I want to debug polygons. Here is an example of how I use it (body is a reference to a ShapeRenderer) http://pastebin.com/pQ4CWGg4

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if there is class for this but i came up with a simple idea.

People believed that sun rotates around earth for years. Because they saw it from earth.
Lets assume rotating square is our world and actually not rotating. In both way we know when is day or night.

Look at those pictures and you will understand better.

[image]

This case is harder to check collision.

[image]

And this case is easier. But actually two cases are same.

So just change case to 2.

You know

- Rotation angle of square/rectangle
- Width and height of square/rectangle
- You can find angle between circle and center point of rectangle/square.

Here is what it will look like in square/rectangle class.

```
public boolean check_collision(Player player)
{
 Vector2 pvector=new Vector2(player.xcenter , player.ycenter);
 Vector2 svector=new Vector2(this.xcenter , this.ycenter);
 float radi=player.radius;
 if( pvector.dst2(svector) < 
 (width + radi) * (width + radi) + 
 (height + radi) * (height + radi) )// dont check if player is too far for collision
 {
  Vector2 rvector= pvector.sub(svector);// rvector from square center to player center
  rvector.setangle(rvector.angle()+ this.rotation);//make sure rotations is CCW
  pvector=rvector.add(svector); //new player vector to check collision
  return new Rectangle(pvector.x-radi/2f ,pvector.y-radi/2f,radi,radi).overlaps(new Rectangle(svector.x-width/2f ,svector.y-height/2f,width,height));
  //assume that player is also rectangle because we already checked worst case with if condition.
 }
 return false;     
}
```